# enable "Reuse query results" in athena using cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

I want to create a cloudformation template for athena queries , there is an option on the console to enable "Reuse query results" for a certain time , how to enable that same feature using a cloudformation template

did not find the option anywhere